# Trying to print/call to/ or alert an object within an array: Getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, undefined

First year @ coding, this is very basic code style for js. Everything I look at to research for help is usually to complex for me to adapt into my basic code. Currently I've got this array I've created, and I'm trying to, in the end game, print out the "course_number, course_title, course_unit" object values onto a page. I'm also trying to modify them as well, but deleting or changing the values.

I'm just trying to call to CIS:0 right now and it's coming up as undefined. Do I need to use Object.create(CIS.___) or am I missing something here. I can't use the "new" function instead of Object.create

Tearing my hair out.

```
var cuesta = {
  BUS_ED: {
    CIS: [{
        "course_number": "231",
        "course_title": "Fundementals of Computer Science 1",
        "Course Unit": "4"
      },
      {
        "course_number": "201",
        "course_title": "Intro to Computer Science",
        "Course Unit": "3"
      },
      {
        "course_number": "201",
        "course_title": "Discrete Structures",
        "Course Unit": "3"
      }
    ],
  }
};

alert(CIS[0]["course_number"]); // coming out as undefined
```

sorry for the mess, it has to stay in this type of structure because we haven't advanced further.

Z

Comment: cuesta['BUS_ED']['CIS'][0]["course_number"]   ... https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hgrg8zbu/

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't try that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the variable then all the separate elements in the data structure. You've almost got it. First `cuesta` then `BUS_ED` is an object, and then the rest you've got.

```
alert(cuesta.BUS_ED.CIS[0]["course_number"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful when you use the term undefined as in javascript 'undefined' is a speical value, so you had me a little confused. undefind is not the same as is not defined. / yes, javascript is weird.

```
Correct:
alert(cuesta.BUS_ED.CIS[0]["course_number"]); 

var cuesta = { // Object
  BUS_ED: { // new Object in object
    CIS: [{ // array of objects in object.
```

Hope this helps.